# Why is there background laughter in The Big Bang Theory 12x15 @11.30?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

The scene I'm, talking about is when Sheldon wakes up and makes himself a cereal breakfast.

[image: Sheldon in the kitchen]

There's literally nothing that gives away Leonard sleeping on his couch and nothing else comical that would be a reason to that laughter?

I've read an article about TBBT creation, and they mentioned that on TBBT each comic scene gets tested on the audience and goes unedited into production only if the audience laughs.

There's nothing comical up to the moment camera goes off to the coach revealing Leonard, so **why on Earth did they edit background laughter there?**

<sub>I do realize that jokes on TBBT have gotten way downhill over time, but it's clearly way different.</sub>

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not watch that particular episode. But is it possible that something happened off-camera (e.g. leonard lying on the couch) that made the audience (who might have been on set) laugh?

Comment: @BestGuess I don’t really get the reason behind adding this, if the joke isn’t explicit. From my point of view, it is almost as show creators are trying to show audience like there’s soon gonna be a funny moment, don’t forget to laugh. Ymmv, of course

Comment: Maybe the creators want to show that the audience is having a good time. Maybe they particularly liked the reaction of the crowd and kept it in for that reason. Or maybe the joke is simply that there is no joke. Just a very ordinary situation. Humor is funny sometimes. And just for the record, i would prefer not having canned laughs myself.;)

Comment: It could just be that the show is terrible and has a laugh track that rarely makes sense.

Comment: Big Bang is shot in front of a live audience, its entirely possible that the version released could have been the 2nd or 200th take, and something from an earlier take made the audience laugh, which when that time comes in the final take theey laughed expecting it to happen again

Answer (score 3):

I've rewatched the episode and the audience laughs when:

- Sheldon yawns
- Sheldon looks forward with a weird expression
- Sheldon is mixing the cereal with the milk and walking

In my opinion, the audience laughs because:

- Sheldon faces and expressions
- Sheldon is kind of sleepy and grumpy
- The fact that Sheldon has some kind of morning routine
- The scene is too quiet and they added the laughs.
- I also think some of the laughs are from people seeing Leonard on the couch before us viewers.

I also chuckled a little bit during the scene before I knew Leonard was in the couch, Sheldon is just humorous...

Comment: But that does make *very little* sense or am I missing something?

Comment: @NikitaNeganov I agree, as you said, "the jokes on TBBT have gotten way downhill over time"...

Comment: @NikitaNeganov I can sit through a TBBT marathon without laughing, so I guess to some people the whole series doesn't make any sense. For me, the overuse of laugh tracks is killing it.